# Android Cloud Save causes App to Freeze for 20+ seconds

Tags: android, cloud, prime31

When I save data to the android cloud using Prime31's PlayGameServices plugin the app is non-responsive for 20+ seconds before returning to normal function. I am using the latest Unity3d engine and Android API 19 is installed.
http://prime31.com/docs#androidPlayGameServices

The save data is a 40k-90k character base-64 string, and I save it with the following functions

- PlayGameServices.setStateData( save_data, 0 );
- PlayGameServices.updateCloudDataForKey( 0, true );

And I retrieve it with

- PlayGameServices.loadCloudDataForKey( 0, true );

The length of the freeze correlates to the size of the file.  The larger the file, the longer it stays frozen.

I am at my wits end trying to figure out what could possibly be causing this!  I can reduce the save string size to 14k-30k characters using string compression, but that is not a good enough solution.

Thank you for reading,

-Mikal Saltveit

**p.s. here is our android manifest**
http://saltve.it/workstuff/AndroidMainfest.txt

Comment: Sounds like you're connecting to the internet on your application's UI Thread which is causing it to freeze until it's finished the request. Anytime you're ever making a web request, you should be doing it in an asynchronous background thread; not the main UI thread. When the request is finished, you can post back to the main thread with a Handler.

Comment: Any idea how I do that in Unity?
I call the function from Monobehaviours Update ( )

Comment: I uploaded the android manifest
http://saltve.it/workstuff/AndroidMainfest.txt